# How do I optimizing OTP Delivery Latency in Web App?

Tags: latency, one-time-password

I'm facing an issue with the OTP delivery latency in a web application I've developed. Specifically, I've integrated a third-party OTP service, and I've observed that the initial OTP delivery takes around 5 minutes, which is considerably high in terms of latency.

Interestingly, after the first request in a day, the latency time is significantly reduced to approximately 0.8 seconds. I'm looking for insights and advice on how to optimize the initial OTP delivery time to make it more instantaneous.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation or have suggestions on tweaks or improvements to the architecture? Your expertise and recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

no ideal yet, thinking of CDN